# Saving grayscale in CMYK using libjpeg in c

Tags: c, jpeg, grayscale, libjpeg, cmyk

If this function does what I think it does, it seems that on my machine at least in CMYK, C=0, M=0, Y=0 and K=0 does not correspond to white! What is the problem?

`float *arr` is a float array with `size` elements. I want to save this array as a JPEG with [IJG](http://www.ijg.org/)'s libjpeg in two color spaces upon demand: `g`: Gray scale and `c`: CMYK. I follow their example and make the input `JSAMPLE *jsr` array with the number of `JSAMPLE` elements depending on the color space: `size` elements for gray scale and `4*size` elements for CMYK. `JSAMPLE` is just another name for `unsigned char` on my machine at least. The full program can be seen [on Github](https://github.com/makhlaghi/fits2jpg/blob/master/src/arr2jpg.c). This is how I fill `jsr`:

```
void
floatfilljsarr(JSAMPLE *jsr, float *arr, size_t size, char color)
{
  size_t i;
  double m;
  float min, max;

  /* Find the minimum and maximum of the array:*/
  fminmax(arr, size, &min, &max);
  m=(double)UCHAR_MAX/((double)max-(double)min);

  if(color=='g')
    {
      for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        jsr[i]=(arr[i]-min)*m;
    }
  else
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
        jsr[i*4+3]=(arr[i]-min)*m;
        jsr[i*4]=jsr[i*4+1]=jsr[i*4+2]=0;
      }
}
```

I should note that `color` has been checked before this function to be either `c` or `g`.
I then write the JPEG image exactly as the `example.c` program in `libjpeg`'s source.

Here is the output after printing both images in a TeX document. Grayscale is on the left and CMYK is on the right. Both images are made from the same ordered array, so the bottom left element (the first in the array as I have defined it and displayed it here) has JSAMPLE value 0 and the top right element has JSAMPLE value 255.

[image: grayscale (left) and CMYK (right) comparison.]

Why aren't the two images similar? Because of the different nature, I would expect the CMYK image to be reversed with its bottom being bright and its top being black. Their displaying JSAMPLE values (the only value in grayscale and the K channel in CMYK) are identical, but this output I get is not what I expected! The CMYK image is also brighter to the top, but very faintly!

It seems that C=0, M=0, Y=0 and K=0 does not correspond to white at least with this algorithm and on my machine!?! How can I set white when I only what to change the K channel and keep the rest zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer my self. First I tried setting all four colors to the same value. It did produce a reasonable result but the output was not inverted as I expected. Such that the pixel with the largest value in all four colors was white, not black!

It was then that it suddenly occurred to me that somewhere in the process, either in IJG's `libjpeg` or in general in the JPEG standard I have no idea which, CMYK colors are reversed. Such that for example a Cyan value of 0 is actually interpreted as `UCHAR_MAX` on the display or printing device and vice versa. If this was the solution, the fact that the image in the question was so dark and that its grey shade was the same as the greyscale image could easily be explained (since I set all three other colors to zero which was actually interpreted as the maximum intensity!).

So I set the first three CMYK colors to the full range (=`UCHAR_MAX`):

```
jsr[i*4]=jsr[i*4+1]=jsr[i*4+2]=UCHAR_MAX /* Was 0 before! */;
```

Then to my surprise the image worked. The greyscale (left) shades of grey are darker, but atleast generally everything can be explained and is reasonably similar. I have checked separately and the absolute black color is identical in both, but the shades of grey in grey scale are darker for the same pixel value.

[image: On monitor]

After I checked them on print (below) the results seemed to differ less, although the shades of grey in greys-scale are darker! Image taken with my smartphone!

[image: On paper]

Also, until I made this change, on a normal image viewer (I am using Scientific Linux), the image would be completely black, that is why I thought I can't see a CMYK image! But after this correction, I could see the CMYK image just as an ordinary image. Infact using `Eye of GNOME` (the default image viewer in GNOME), the two nearly appear identical.

Answer (score 1):

Try inverting your K channel:

```
       jsr[i*4+3]= (m - ((arr[i]-min)*m);
```

Comment: Thanks, I inverted the image by subtracting every value from `UCHAR_MAX`, because `(arr[i]-min)*m` is between `0` to `UCHAR_MAX`. I updated the question. It is still doesn't become as clear as the grayscale.

Comment: Make sure "white" is being represented as 0 for CYMK, and that "black" is UCHAR_MAX. I think your original grayscale (which is really RGB, where R=G=B) formula was slightly different, and was accurately mapping your {min,max} to the range 0..UCHAR_MAX.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make sure how CMYK defines black and white?

Comment: CMYK white: C=0, M=0, Y=0, K=0; CMYK black: C/M/Y (undefined really, but 0 saves ink), K={maximum}. Since you are working with grayscale, you can basically think of the K channel as being the opposite of (RGB) grayscale. Depending on your use of the data, don't rule out fun uses of the CMY channels to add contrast to the image.

Comment: I updated the question with a new array as input. It seems that C=0, M=0, Y=0 and K=0 does not correspond to white! Although I agree that in theory it should! So I guess I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what!?!